# Github mac git use more than one account

Tags: git, macos, github, version-control, keychain

I have two accounts on Github, each with a specific use.

I would like to make sure that every time I push my name and password, I can do uploud with the right account.

But it doesn't happen, I use the https connection for this instead of the ssh.

Now going on the keychain, I saw that there are two keys found.
One key for userA and one key for userB, both for Github.

Can you give me a hand?

Comment: This article outlines a solution: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/manage-multiple-github-accounts-the-ssh-way-2dadc30ccaca/

Answer (score 5):

Get yourself a personal access token as described in https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token

Once you have a personal access token you can use it as a password for your account. So you get one for each account.

To use your personal access token add your github account name and use the token as password to the http URL using the `username:passowrd@` syntax. For example if you want to clone my httpstress repo you can do:

```
git clone https://YOUR_GITUB_ACCOUNT:YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN@github.com/slebetman/httpstress.git
```

If you have already cloned your repo you can edit your `.git/config` file and edit your github URL to include your account name and personal access token. Find the following section in your `.git/config` file:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/slebetman/httpstress.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

And change it as follows:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://YOUR_GITUB_ACCOUNT:YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN@github.com/slebetman/httpstress.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: is this recommended way? arent you storing access token in plain file which should be avoided!?

Answer (score -1):

This information is documented in the Git FAQ.  There's an explanation of [how to do this with HTTPS](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIusemultipleaccountswiththesamehostingproviderusingHTTP) and [how to do it with SSH](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIusemultipleaccountswiththesamehostingproviderusingSSH).

If you have a recent version of Git, you can read the FAQ by running `man gitfaq`.

Comment: First, you might as well have posted a link to let-me-google-it-for-you. At SO it is encouraged to post the solution along with the source. 

Secondly, OPs question was MacOS and GitHub specific. Adding the account name with @ before the provider solves differentiating between accounts, but how to store authentication information for two github accounts (personal access token nowadays since github does not allow credentials login anymore), is not explained in the git faq.

Comment: Those are the correct directions for GitHub as well as every other site using Basic authentication.  There is nothing different about macOS or GitHub here; it works everywhere.  The only difference on GitHub is that your password is a PAT, not your web login password.  I wrote the FAQ entry and I am certain it works for GitHub.